# how to optimize flutter dio token refresh request only one time

Tags: flutter

Now I am using dio(`4.0.0`) as my http client in flutter 2.x, I want to refresh the token, but now I encount a problem: when the auth token is invalid, I just want only one request send to server to refresh token. But now the http request is async and when the token invalid, many request send to server to refresh token, althrough finnaly the token could successfully refreshed, but you know the server must handle some invalid repeat token refresh request.What should I to to optimize the client only one request send to server to refresh token? this is the code I am using now:

```
class AppInterceptors extends InterceptorsWrapper {
  @override
  Future<void> onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (!options.headers.containsKey("token")) {
      String? token = await storage.read(key: "token");
      options.headers["token"] = token;
    }
    handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    autoLogin(response);
    return super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }

  @override
  Future onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    return super.onError(err, handler);
  }

  void autoLogin(Response response) async {
    String loginInvalidCode = ResponseStatus.LOGIN_INVALID.statusCode;
    String notLoginCode = ResponseStatus.NOT_LOGIN.statusCode;
    String statusCode = response.data["statusCode"];
    if (statusCode == loginInvalidCode || statusCode == notLoginCode) {
      Dio dio = RestClient.createDio();
      String? userName = await storage.read(key: "username");
      String? password = await storage.read(key: "password");
      if (userName != null && password != null) {
        refreshAuthToken(dio, userName, password, response);
      } else {
        NavigationService.instance.navigateToReplacement("login");
      }
    }
  }

  void refreshAuthToken(Dio dio, String userName, String password, Response response) async {
    dio.lock();
    try {
      AuthResult result = await Auth.login(username: userName, password: password, loginType: LoginType.PHONE);
      if (result.result == Result.ok) {
        // resend a request to fetch data
        Dio req = RestClient.createDio();
        req.request(response.requestOptions.path);
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      CruiseLogHandler.logErrorException("login failed", e);
    } finally {
      dio.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

the better way to only send one request to server to refresh token. But I do not know how to do  it. I want the refresh logic better smooth.

Comment: Your issue here is that serveral requests are made and the token is invalid, all of them will try to refresh the token from the server because of the interceptor? Did I got that right?

Comment: yes, many request are send to server, but I just want one request send to server and other request should stop and wait the token refresh and upate the local cahe, any better way to make it work like this.any suggestiones? @croxx5f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only posting this as an answer because its cumbersome to write all this in the comments.

I was about to recommend to you [locking](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#lockunlock-the-interceptors) the interceptors , but you already do so.

**Even though that you have repeated requests?**

The other thing I see is that you are unconditionally calling the autologin in `onResponse`

That I think could be more granular as:

```dart
  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) async {
if(response?.statusCode == 401){
// I think you should move the locking up here so you stop other requests earlier.
//   dio.interceptors.requestLock.lock();
   
await autoLogin(response); // You had a missing await here

// dio.interceptors.requestLock.unlock()
}
    return super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }
```

I also noted that you pass a new client as `Dio dio = RestClient.createDio();` is that a singleton?, because if not you might be locking another client